# Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.Windows.Controls.TextBox' error when trying to square root a text box

Tags: c#

i am trying to square root a text box value and output it into a different text box. This is what i have so far:

```
private void ButtonSquareRoot_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    double Input1double = Convert.ToDouble(TextBoxInput1.Text);
    double VarTextBoxAnswer = Math.Sqrt(Input1double);
    TextBoxAnswer = VarTextBoxAnswer.ToString();
}
```

it comes up with this error message:

```
 Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
```

Error   CS0029  Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.Windows.Controls.TextBox'    calculator  c:\users\user\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\calculator\calculator\MainWindow.xaml.cs    125 Active

line 125 is the one starting with TextBoxAnswer

if you have any idea how to fix this please help! If i haven't been specific enough then please reply and i will give more information.

Comment: `TextBoxAnswer.Text=VarTextBoxAnswer.ToString();`

Answer (score 6):

replace

```
TextBoxAnswer = VarTextBoxAnswer.ToString();
```

with

```
TextBoxAnswer.Text = VarTextBoxAnswer.ToString();
```

You have to write the result into the `Text` property of the `TextBox` object.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue working with windows forms.

I simply renamed the affected columns in the database suggested in the error and it simply vanished.

Comment: The question don't seem to say anything about any database.

Comment: @Alejandro True but it most certainly will involve it. Regardless this is a similar scenario i encountered and how i overcame .